# Views Filter to display field only if it matches a certain value

Tags: views

how do I display a field in views ONLY if the value matches a certain specified value?

Comment: Hi, can you give some example for you case? just to elaborate it. is filter criterion not good for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example: I have a field name called "Product". Add FILTER CRITERIA. Filter choose content and search Product. Save the views and click the recently added FILTER CRITERIA. You will able set a setting like Product = Book.
This will appear if you choose Autocomplete
[image]
This will appear if you choose select
[image]